# Too little RAM in Kaa Server

Tags: installation, ram, kaa

I want to run a test with KAA, so I was trying to install the sandbox in my laptop but it has only 4GB in RAM, so when I try to set up the Virtual Machine the system won't let me set up over 1,6GB and the VM won't start.

So I was trying to install in other old laptop so I installed Ubuntu 16,04 and I followed all the step by step instructions in Kaaproyect's WEB. I could do it, but when I try to start the server can't do it. I was checking the Log error and say me that the problem is in the Java's Virtual machine, can't start because only have 2GB in RAM. I need to test a Little application so is it possible change this requirement in the Java machine and start the system?

PS: I can't buy more Ram.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use amazon AWS. The basic installation where you can run Kaa is free for one year, and it runs quite well there.